# What does function: 0x7f452394c4b0 mean (context in body)

Tags: lua

I was messing around in lua with a random number generator(I was watching a tutorial and the guy went over it
The script I ran ( ran many scripts that got the same thing, but this is the most simple one) was this: `print(math.random)`
I am very new to lua ( just started today) so it is very possible I screwed something up.
Any help would be appreciated
Thanks,
GJW

Comment: `math.random` is a function. `math.random()` is the result of calling it.

Answer (score 2):

`math.random` is a function in Lua's math library.

See https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-math.random

In order to execute the function you must call it.

```
math.random()
```

printing the function value as in `print(math.random)` will print a string representation of that value. `0x7f452394c4b0` is an identifier which is unique to that function value at runtime. This is helpful in debugging.